# Using placeholders in vim

Tags: vim

Given a vim document with multiple occurrences of a specific placeholder, say `<%%>`, I want to be able to jump to the next placeholder from the beginning of the document: More explicitly, if the document is given by

`$\frac{<%%>}{<%%>}$`

I want to press a key such that the first placeholder gets removed, i.e. we have

`$\frac{}{<%%>}$`

where the cursor is at the position of the placeholder and vim is in insert mode.

I'm aware of the vim-latex plugin which implements such a behaviour but only need this one feature. I tried to use the `/-search` of vim but didnt get the cursor position right. 
Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[lh-brackets](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets) provides this feature -- actually [vim-latex placeholder system has been inspired by lh-brackets one](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite.html#latex-suite-credits).

The idea to implement this feature, is:

1. to look for the pattern of the placeholder -- prefer `search()` to know whether something has been found: no selection shall be done otherwise

   Actually doing it correctly may require a couple of calls to `searchpair()` to handle the case where the cursor is in the middle of the placeholder, see [lh-brackets code](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets/blob/05aaec7d82f15c135f97063d534332b3fd388474/plugin/bracketing.base.vim#L268) as `search(..., 'c')` is not enough;
2. select this pattern -- `v` + movement `3<right>` for instance
3. and finally either go into SELECT-mode (<del>`gh`</del> `<c-g>`) or remove the placeholder and go into insert mode (`s`)

If your placeholder pattern is exactly `<%%>`, it'll be quite simple to implement.

```
" I factorize common code without introducing the exact keybinding
" NB: we have to use the ancestor of map-<expr> as the later doesn't
" permit to move the cursor -> we execute the expression register: :h @=
" NB: As said earlier a correct implementation would require to call searchpair()
" twice in case the cursor is within a placeholder, see lh-brackets code
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>(jump-next) @=(search('<%%>') > 0 ? "v3l<c-g>" : '')<cr>
vmap     <silent> <Plug>(jump-next) <c-\><c-n><Plug>(jump-next)
imap     <silent> <Plug>(jump-next) <c-\><c-n><Plug>(jump-next)

" Tests shall be done in a real plugin before binding to the chosen shortcut: µ, <f3>, <c-j>, <tab>...
nmap <silent> µ <Plug>(jump-next)
vmap <silent> µ <Plug>(jump-next)
imap <silent> µ <Plug>(jump-next)
```

If sometimes it could become `<%somestring%>`, then I would definitively recommend using lh-brackets or any snippet engine that already takes care of this -- for instance, [mu-template](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template) would permit to use your exact snippets/templates by changing locally the default placeholder characters with `VimL: let s:marker_open  = '<%'` + 
`VimL: let s:marker_close = '%>'` (I'm also maintaining mu-template which depends on lh-brackets).

NB: lh-brackets also provides surrounding (non intrusive), and bracket pairs insertion (can be deactivated: add `:let g:cb_no_default_brackets = 1` in your `.vimrc`)

Comment: Thanks, but what do you mean by the search()-function? Just the /-search of vim? How do I call the search-function in a map or in vim?
Using the /-search your answer seems to work exactly as it should.

Comment: If `/<%%>` fails, you'll get an error. With `nnoremap <silent> µ @=(search('<%%>') >= 0 ? "v3l<c-g>" : '')<cr>`, it gets silent

Comment: Sorry for my dumb questions,but I dont get it to work. I edited my .vimrc file and added the line

`nnoremap <F3> <silent> µ @=(search('<%%>') >= 0 ? "v3l<c-g>" : '')<cr>`

I never used this mu-symbol in any commands before...

Comment: `µ` is just a key I have on my keyboard that I use when I'm testing mappings. Use whatever you wish, like `<F3>`, to navigate. BTW, insert and visual mode mappings will also need to be defined (they are the same, just escape before)

Comment: Ah I see; thats brilliant, works absolutely great; maybe one should use > 0 instead of >= 0 here.

Comment: Indeed, I've mixed up with other functions. I'll shortly edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using a [macro](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Macros) might help.

In your example, use `/<%%>` to search for your placeholder. Then `gg` will take you at the beginning of the document.

Then start the macro with `qa` for instance.  Go to the next occurrence of your placeholder with `n`. Then, `ca<` will remove the placeholder. `C-o q` will stop recording, while keeping you in insertion mode.

To go to and replace the next placeholder, just do `@a` (execute the macro stored in register `a`)

Comment: Yes, this is quite the feature I want to have. However, I would prefer to use a key since I want to use this feature very often for jumping around in the code. But your answer should work in a keymap instead of a macro by the same commands, right?

Comment: Yes, I think @phd answer is brilliant to this regard.

Answer (score 2):

Does this mapping help?

```
:nmap %% /<%%><cr>ni
```

It executes a search (`/<%%><cr>`), repeats the search with `n` to skip the 1st placeholder and goes to the second. Then it switches (`i`) to Insert Mode.